# What's the best way to save multiple variables into NSUserdefaults and display on another view controller in the order saved?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

New swift guy here! I'm having problems conceptualizing how to store this information of a location with multiple details. Is user defaults the best way? Perhaps json array file?

I've got two view controllers 1. favorites and 2. info.

FavoritesViewController displays multiple groups of data in the order in which they were favorited like this

---

```
Favorites

Group 1             Remove button
- Name of location
- Address
- latitude
- longitude
- Hours

then continues groups
```

---

On the infoViewController it shows locations from a database. It has a favorite button which stores it for use in the favoritesViewController.

```
  @IBAction func favoriteThis(_ sender: Any) { 

       // check the state of favorited button
          if toggleState == 1 {
            toggleState = 2
            favoriteThis.setTitle("favorited!", forState: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(toggleState, forKey: "favorited")

        } else {
            toggleState = 1
         favoriteThis.setTitle("favorite", forState: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(toggleState, forKey: "favorited")

        }

        //set the current values to variables

        let name = self.selectedLocation!.name
        let address = self.selectedLocation!.address
        let lat = self.selectedLocation!.latitude
        let long = self.selectedLocation!.longitude

         // set them to an array and store them with a unique id
         let array = [id, name, address, lat, long]

         let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          defaults.set(array, forKey: "FavArray")

   }
```

This does store in the FavArray, but if I need to save and display more than one of these groups in favoriteViewController, What do you think is a better solution to approaching this?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserDefaults is meant for small pieces of data. So instead of using User defaults, I would recommend making your custom PList file (You can think of it as your custom UserDefaults file) special for your array of custom Types.

To solve your problem I created a custom Type which will hold all your location data like so: -

```
struct FavoriteLocation: Codable {
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees

    init(name: String,address: String, latitude: CLLocationDegrees,longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**  Your Custom type should conform to Codable protocol so that it can be encoded and decoded to and from Custom Plist file.

**NEXT:-** 
In your ViewController you can populate an array of this type and use it to save as well as retrieve data from your customPList file. I have summarized everything in a ViewController with Comments as shown below. Let me know if you don't understand any part of it.

```
class CustomPListViewController: UIViewController {

    /// Make your array of Favorite Locations
    let favLocationArray:[FavoriteLocation] = []

   /**
      Create our own directory to save data locally in a custom Plist file, inside our apps Document directory.
      This is used both when writing and retrieving.
     */
    let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("FavoriteLocations.plist")

    /// Save your array in custom PList file (Encode)
    func saveFavoritePLacesInCustomPList(favLocationArray: [FavoriteLocation]) {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(favLocationArray)
            guard let dataFilePath = self.dataFilePath else { return }
            do {
                try data.write(to: dataFilePath)
            } catch {
                // Handle error
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle error
        }

    }


    // Retrieve your saved data (Decode)
    func retrieveFavoriteLocations() {
        guard let filePath = self.dataFilePath else {return }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            do {
                let favoriteLocationsArray = try decoder.decode(Array<FavoriteLocation>.self, from: data)
                // This is your data ready to use
                print(favoriteLocationsArray)

            } catch  {
                // Handle error
            }

        } catch  {
           // Handle error
        }

    }



}
```

**How does it work?**

We are using `PropertyListEncoder` to `encode` ie to transform your custom object into a format which can be saved in .plist file. and to get your data back to your app's model (`FavoriteLocation`) we use `PropertyListDecoder` which does the opposite ie `decode` .plist formatted data back to your custom Object.

**How to view your custom .plist file?**

On your `viewDidLoad` method call `print(dataFilePath!)`
This will print the full file path which you can naviagate to it and see your `FavoriteLocations.plist`

Comment: Hi @DrewPeer, I saw your previous comment and edited my answer to include two more sections . Please scroll down to the answer and check "How does it work" section as well as "How to view your custom .plist file". 
If this solve your issue please don't forget to mark this as accepted answer, cheers.

Comment: Okay so your struct FavoriteLocation: Codable should be located in my ibaction button function at the bottom? Also noticed in the CustomPlistViewController the  let favLocationArray:[FavoriteLocation] = [] Throws an error Use of undeclared type 'FavoriteLocation'. I will accept this answer shortly.

Comment: struct FavoriteLocation should be in a separate file for best practice so you can make a separate file FavoriteLocation.swift and put the struct there. then you won't get that " Use of undeclared type" errror.

Comment: Oh it's in a separate file, but I get the error still.

Comment: If the class is definitely there and using the same name then that error must be Xcode minor issue, Can you try to build the app and see if the error still exist?

Comment: So I should have 3 files to do this task?  favoritelocations.plist, favoritelocations.swift  - has the struct code now says Type 'FavoriteLocation' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'  number 3 file is CustomPListViewController.swift?

Comment: FavoriteLocations.plist is auto-generated for every user, no need to manually create that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198261/discussion-between-mussa-charles-and-drew-peer).